# ViewPager, Dagger injection, MVP design

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewpager, dagger-2, android-mvp

It came up to me when I was designing my app structure. Basically, the app has a tab layout and some fragments associated with it (let's say 2). My goal is to have presenter being injected into activity or fragment(view). However, the presenter is interacting mostly with the fragment, where UI logic lives) The goal is to have component tight to a specific scope too. Here are 3 designs I have.

1. 2 modules, each provides a specific presenter. Have 1 component that associates these two modules. In main activity, build the component and call inject.
2. 2 modules, each provides a specific presenter and associate with 1 component. So each fragment will have its own component and build it and inject it in the corresponding fragment.
3. 1 modules, providing 2 presenters. Have 1 component that associates these two modules. In main activity, build the component and call inject.

Comment: and? Please ask a question.